# PHP mb_ereg_replace not replacing UTF-8 chars

Tags: php

I'm trying to remove special chars by allowing only the patter bellow.

> '/[^A-Za-z0-9ÀÁÉÍÓÚÇÃÕÂÊÔàáéíóúçãõâêô\~!@#\$\%\^\&*()-_\=+\|{}[]\;:\'\"\<>\,./\?\s\n]/'

But when I run my script, it returns all characters not allowed © ® ñ ö

```
mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8');
$string = 'teste © ® ñ ö ';
echo mb_ereg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9ÀÁÉÍÓÚÇÃÕÂÊÔàáéíóúçãõâêô\~\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\-\_\=\+\|\{\}\[\]\;\:\'\"\<\>\,\.\/\?\s\n]/', '', $string);
```

**Return:**
teste © ® é ñ ö

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
mb_regex_encoding('utf-8');
$pattern = "[^A-Za-z0-9ÀÁÉÍÓÚÇÃÕÂÊÔàáéíóúçãõâêô~!@#$%^&*()-_=+|{}\[\];:'\"<>,.\/\?\s\n]+";
$in = "teste © ® ñ ö";
echo mb_ereg_replace($pattern,"", $in);
```

There [is a difference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg-replace.php) in how you setup the pattern in ereg vs preg

Comment: So helpful! Instead of `mb_ereg_replace('/[^A-...` user `mb_ereg_replace('"[^A-...`. Quotation marks instead slash!